Filtro de fechas en PHP
tengo el siguiente problema que no logro solucionar. Tengo una tabla donde tengo guardados registros, entre ellos un campo llamado Fecha que guarda un datetime. Pues bien, cuando voy a filtrar filtro de la siguiente manera (Es un ejemplo simplificacdo, el filtro es más complejo y está sanitizado):
$consulta = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE Fecha >= '$fecha1' AND Fecha <= '$fecha2'");

El problema es que se pongo en fecha 1 y fecha 2 el día de hoy, por ejemplo, aunque haya registros no me los muestra. Si pongo en fecha 1 el día de hoy y en fecha 2 el día de mañana ya si me los muestra. He probado tambien con BETWEEN pero tengo el mismo resultado, ¿Sabeis como arreglarlo?
Gracias.

Aunque esté sanitizado, es mejor idea parametrar la consulta en vez de concatenar directamente.

Ya que el campo es un datetime y evidentemente vos estas pasando fechas sin horas, una solución es agregarle la hora a $fecha2. Por ejemplo, si $fecha2 es igual a 2024-04-03, entonces agregarle la hora, 2024-04-03 23:59:59

Gracias @RodrigoRamírez por el consejo, estoy actualizando este programa poco a poco pero aun tengo unas cuantas consultas así. Y Marcos efectivamente se soluciono así (Al menos hasta que aparametrice las consultas). Gracias!
